# How can I apply cuda to custom model in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

The type of inputs is dictionary of tensors. So while training I convert device to cuda to use gpu. And my custom model is like above. Also I assigned cuda to the model.

```
class EmbeddingLayer(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(EmbeddingLayer, self).__init__()

    # other features
    self.other_features_embedding = []
    for feature_name in OTHER_FEATURES:
      vocabulary = CATEGORICAL_FEATURES_WITH_VOCABULARY[feature_name]
      embedding_dims = int(math.sqrt(len(vocabulary)))
      embedding = nn.Embedding(len(vocabulary)+1, embedding_dims)
      self.other_features_embedding.append(embedding)

    # transformer features
    item_vocabulary = CATEGORICAL_FEATURES_WITH_VOCABULARY['item']
    self.item_embedding_dims = int(math.sqrt(len(item_vocabulary)))
    self.item_embedding = nn.Embedding(len(item_vocabulary)+1, self.item_embedding_dims)

  def forward(self, inputs):

    # other features
    encoded_other_features = []
    for i, feature_name in enumerate(OTHER_FEATURES):
      embedding = self.other_features_embedding[i](inputs[feature_name])
      encoded_other_features.append(embedding)

    encoded_other_features = torch.cat(encoded_other_features, -1)

    # transformer features
    encoded_sequence_item = self.item_embedding(inputs['sequence_item'])
    encoded_target_item = self.item_embedding(inputs['target_item'])

    positions = inputs['target_timestamp'].repeat(sequence_length-1, 1).transpose(0, 1) - inputs['sequence_timestamp']
    encoded_positions = positions.repeat(1, self.item_embedding_dims).reshape(-1, self.item_embedding_dims, sequence_length-1).transpose(1,2)

    encoded_sequence_item_with_position = encoded_sequence_item + encoded_positions
    encoded_transformer_features = torch.cat((encoded_sequence_item_with_position, encoded_target_item.reshape(-1, 1, self.item_embedding_dims)), 1)

    return encoded_other_features, encoded_transformer_features


class BST(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, hidden_units, dropout, num_heads):
    super(BST, self).__init__()

 

    ...

    self.embedding_layer = EmbeddingLayer()

    ...

  
  def forward(self, inputs):
    other_features, transformer_features = self.embedding_layer(inputs)
    
    ...

    return self.output(features)
```

```
model = BST([256, 128], 0.3, 1)
model.to(device)
```

```
def train(model, optimizer, dataloader):
  model.train()
  for inputs in tqdm(dataloader, total=len(dataloader)):
    
    for k, v in inputs.items():
      inputs[k] = v.to(device)

    model.zero_grad()
    pred = model(inputs)

    ...
```

But following error occurs:

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper__index_select)
```

I think the error occurs at embedding in EmbeddingLayer. How can I fix this error to use gpu while training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list of `nn.Module` is not registering the embedding layers as sub modules of your layer. In order to properly register a list of modules you should use `nn.ModuleList`. Therefore, you should add the following right after the loop in your `__init__` function:

```
embeddings = []
for feature_name in OTHER_FEATURES:
    vocabulary = CATEGORICAL_FEATURES_WITH_VOCABULARY[feature_name]
    embedding_dims = int(math.sqrt(len(vocabulary)))
    embedding = nn.Embedding(len(vocabulary)+1, embedding_dims)
    embeddings.append(embedding)

self.other_features_embedding = nn.ModuleList(embeddings)
```